# Best way of populating normalized SQL database in python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Suppose I have table Users, with some of its attributes being 'name', 'idCountry', 'idLanguage', 'idSchool',
and also have Countries, Languages, and Schools tables.

example of what I receive through an API: ['John','Italy','Italian','School1']

So when I want to insert user John, I have to check if a country called 'Italy' exists in Countries table, if not, create it, and either way retrieve its idCountry, then the same for Language and School, and then create user 'John' with the retrieved ID's.
Is it ok doing it this way? Is there any more efficient way to do this? or any framework or library in python that makes it automatically.
Right now I'm using SQLalchemy to make SQL queries like

`insert into countries values 'italy'`

Comment: As asked, your question can prompt opinionated answers asking for *best way*. Additionally, you are asking for software/library recommendations. Both of these aspects are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on StackOverflow. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on your own, find an implementation,  and then given an earnest attempt. Come back with any *specific* questions regarding your attempt.

Comment: My implementation is using plain sql and doing the 'algorithm' I described, I'm asking if that's okay and for examples on how other people solve this problem better, or if there's any software made for this

Comment: Using ids for values (that somehow supposedly identify them better than they identify themselves) has nothing to do with DB normalization.